# CLIENT_ERROR: authorization failed for primary source and source version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pipeline

I opened a free AWS account to learn and created an Administrator user group and user in IAM for myself.

I am following a tutorial "[Automating your API testing with AWS CodeBuild, AWS CodePipeline, and Postman](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automating-your-api-testing-with-aws-codebuild-aws-codepipeline-and-postman/)."

I am getting the error CLIENT_ERROR: authorization failed for primary source and source version in the DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase of the Build transition in CodePipeline.

I followed the directions in an earlier post at [AWS CodeBuild failed CLIENT_ERROR: authorization failed for primary source and source version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64300151/aws-codebuild-failed-client-error-authorization-failed-for-primary-source-and-s) with no success.

I added and attached a policy for connection-permissions in my service role as directed like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codestar-connections:UseConnection",
            "Resource": "insert connection ARN here"
        }
    ]
}
```

Later, I changed the Action above to

```
"codepipeline:GetPipelineState"
```

I added and attached a policy for GitPull like so:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "codecommit:GitPull"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Effect": "Allow"
},
```

I have disconnected and reconnected my connection to GitHub and also tried creating a new personal access token with no success.
I have tried changing my S3 to public and Allow with

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried updating my node in the source code to 16.18.0.

I am stuck.  The resources I have found keep pointing me to the same AWS page I mentioned.  I don't know what else to do.  I would appreciate any help.

My repo is located at https://github.com/venushofler/my-aws-codepipeline-codebuild-with-postman.git

[image: Pipeline image]

[image: CodeBuild image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the above was to add a default set of access permissions to my users, groups, and roles in my account.  I found documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/setting-up.html which in part stated, "To add a default set of CodeBuild access permissions to an IAM group or IAM user, choose Policy Type, AWS Managed, and then do the following:

To add full access permissions to CodeBuild, select the box named AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess, choose Policy Actions, and then choose Attach. "

This worked to allow the Build and Deploy stage to succeed.
[image]